# Is there any way to solve df(t)/dt = 0 for t and f(tsolved) value if we know F(s), the Laplace transform of f?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, laplace-transform, global-optimization

I am trying to know max(f(t)) value but I have only F(s) equation of it and I thought that by solving df(t)/dt == 0 by Laplace using F(s) which is s*F(s) == 0, I can easily solve what is t for max(f(t)) and using solved t I will find f(tsolved) value which will give me global max or min value.

Two questions: how can I solve df(t)/dt == 0 diff equation by F(s) and how can I get the value of f(tsolved) again from F(s)

Comment: I'm fairly confident that this wouldn't be possible. If we consider the Fourier which in hand way sense can be got by putting $s=j\omega$, then you are moving from time to frequency domains and you cannot deduce time domain characterstics from the frequency domain signal. But, probably I'm wrong. Or, there will be a better way to explain it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Is it possible to solve df(t)/dt == 0 differential equation by F(s)?

Comment: AFAIK, you have to get $f(t)$ using any initial conditions (f(0) etc) given and solve the maximum. Actually the Laplace of the differential has a constant term dependent on $f(0)$. So, it is not directly possible to solve $\frac{df(t)}{dt} = 0$ from the Laplace transform.

Comment: If we know f(0), we can solve t which makes df(t)/dt == 0, is that correct and how can we do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two  very different things  one might mean by "Solve $f'(t)=0$"; it's not at all clear from the OP which one is intended:

> > **Problem 1.** "Given"  $f$,  find $t$ such that $f'(t)=0$.
> >
> > **Problem 2.** Find $f$ such that $f'(t)=0$ for all $t$.

Indeed, it seems  possible that the OP doesn't appreciate the distinction. The two tags ordinary-differential-equations and global-optimization would appear to indicate this, since the ode tag is relevant to Problem 2 but not to Problem 1, and vice-versa for the optimization  tag.

Anyway, it seems  very unlikely that the Laplace transform can be used for Problem 1.  Otoh one *could* use the LT on Problem 2, but that would be a very curious thing to do, since the solution to Problem 2 is so  obvious without the LT.

By the way, you have a detail  wrong about how the Laplace transform plays with differential equations: Saying $f'==0$ does **not** say $sF(s)=0$, rather it says $sF(s)-f(0)=0$.

Comment: If we solve sF(s)−f(0)=0 equation and get s, how can we convert s to t

Comment: @ÖmerYıldız Huh? If $F(s)=c/s$ then $f(t)=c$. This is like the first example in the chapter on the Laplace transform in any elementary book on differential equations...

Comment: I need t which makes sF(s) = 0, saying F(s)=c/s  then f(t)=c is not saying how to find t by getting s from sF(s) = 0 equation...

Comment: There's no such  thing as a $t$ that makes $sF(s)=0$; that simply makes no sense. I answered what seems like a sensible version of the question - given $F$, find $f$.